# constraint в Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

Я хочу сделать так, что бы данное изображение всегда было квадратной формы и по центру экрана. При вертикальном расположении экрана изображение граничило с правой и левой стороной экрана. При горизонтальном положении с верхней и нижней границей. Если установить фиксированное расстояние(равное 0) между картинкой, правой границей и левой границей в горизонтальном положение изображение выходит за границы. Я знаю как это можно сделать через код, но хотелось бы понять как осуществить через констрейты.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Я знаю, как это можно сделать через код" – тогда тут никаких проблем быть не должно, если вы констрейнты через код устанавливали. Если вы через код autoresizing mask задавали, то задайте его и в Interface Builder, или уточните вопрос, потому что противоречия между "кодом и констрейнтами" нет.

Answer (score 0):

Добавте top и bottom constraints >= 0, trailing и leading тоже долъны быть  >= 0. Когда вы поворачиваете экран боковые растягивают ваше вью в стороны и из-за ratio оно остаётся квадратным и уходит вверх и вниз за границы.

Answer (score 0):

Если задача показать квадратную картинку на весь экран - берете квадратную картинку, в сториборде делаете `UIImageView` во весь экран и задаете ему  Content Mode = Aspect Fit.